# I can´t connect tb-gateway with thingsboard on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, thingsboard

I need your help...
I configured my Ubuntu 16.04.5 Server as described on https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld/ and https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/getting-started/ but it doesnt realy work.   The tb-gateway.log says:

```
2018-08-02 08:12:17,065 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO o.t.g.service.MqttMessageSender - Sending message [MqttPersistentMessage(id=3156e095-46d0-4e26-a33d-cda11ca330cc, timestamp=0, deviceId=GATEWAY, messageId=905, topic=v1/devices/me/telemetry, payload=[123, 34, 116, 115, 34, 58, 49, 53, 51, 51, 49, 57, 48, 51, 51, 54, 50, 55, 51, 44, 34, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 34, 58, 123, 34, 100, 101, 118, 105, 99, 101, 115, 79, 110, 108, 105, 110, 101, 34, 58, 48, 44, 34, 97, 116, 116, 114, 105, 98, 117, 116, 101, 115, 85, 112, 108, 111, 97, 100, 101, 100, 34, 58, 48, 44, 34, 116, 101, 108, 101, 109, 101, 116, 114, 121, 85, 112, 108, 111, 97, 100, 101, 100, 34, 58, 48, 125, 125])]
2018-08-02 08:12:17,065 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  o.t.g.service.MqttMessageSender - Outgoing queue is not empty. [1] messages are still in progress
2018-08-02 08:12:17,065 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  o.t.g.service.MqttMessageSender - Waiting until all messages are sent before going to the next bucket
2018-08-02 08:12:17,068 [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  o.t.g.s.gateway.MqttGatewayService - Gateway statistics {"ts":1533190336273,"values":{"devicesOnline":0,"attributesUploaded":0,"telemetryUploaded":0}} reported!
```

And reqeats this every minute. So it seams to work. But the Thingsboard cant read the massage. The thingsboard.log file says:

```
2018-08-02 07:54:38,405 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.a.ruleChain.RuleChainActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@54663f30!
2018-08-02 07:54:38,435 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@15327281!
2018-08-02 07:54:38,436 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@29bb19d1!
2018-08-02 07:54:38,475 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@26ee903e!
2018-08-02 07:54:42,226 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@78d307d8!
2018-08-02 07:54:42,295 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@c357f50!
2018-08-02 07:54:42,695 [Akka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2375] WARN  o.t.s.actors.ruleChain.RuleNodeActor - Unknown message: org.thingsboard.server.actors.stats.StatsPersistTick@58f174d1!
```

And reqeats this every hour. So the connection isnt working. On the Thingsboard dashboard the gateway can be configured (eg. Extension) but the "Last Telemetry" doesnt show anything.
Please feel free to ask any question if you need more information.

Best regards

Comment: The problem still exists, but I was able to locate the error, at least mayby..
It seems that thingsboard isnt able to read data from the database, since I can send MQTT massages to it but they arent displayed in the dashboard. It is possible that java isnt working properly.   
Would be nice if somebody has an idea to solve this!   
thanks in advance